# Nuxt.js: Managing CMS collections for a statically generated website

Tags: vue.js, content-management-system, vuex, nuxt.js

On `nuxt generate`, we need to fetch all collections from the CMS. Since our website is completely static, it should be sufficient to fetch every collection only 1 time, and then make them available to all routes.

We run into issues making this happen, without exposing all our websites content to every single route.

We could use vuex to store all the content. However, we don't want a giant store object with all our websites content to be available to the client. Only during the build process, the server should have access to it and pass the content needed to every single route, eg. via `asyncData()`
(remember, we have a statically generated website, therefore `asyncData()` is never called from the client).

Example: We need the `blog` collection on `/blog`, but also on `/blog/:slug`, and on `/press`. Currently we fetch them individually:

```js
// /pages/blog/index.vue
export default {
  asyncData() {
    return fetchArticles();  
  }
}
```

```js
// /pages/blog/_slug.vue
export default {
  asyncData(context) {
    // made available in nuxt.config.js
    return context.payload;
  }
}
```

```js
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  generate: {
    // generate dynamic routes
    routes: async function() {
      const collection = await fetchArticles();
      const result = collection.map(item => {
        return {
          route: `/blog/${item.slug}`,
          // save in payload, to make available in context
          payload: item
        };
      });
      return result;
    }
  }
}
```

Problem: We are fetching the same collection twice. We want to fetch it once, and then make it available to all routes.

Expected result: Being able to

1. fetch every collection only 1 time
2. storing all the collections on the server side only, passing needed content to routes via `asyncData()`
3. on client side, not being able to access that "server-side-store"

Actual result:

- having to refetch the same collection for several routes

Comment: why not just fill /blog/index.vue with context.payload? This way you can manage blog-list content same way as individual posts.

Comment: @DreaMinder because context.payload is only available to the dynamic routes

Comment: however, it would be indeed ideal if the collections could just be made available to the context of every route. I tried it with a plugin, however, it runs for every single route. ideally there was a plugin that simply runs 1 time before generating all routes

Answer (score 1):

Just fill your /blog/index.vue the same way as your single blog post, with payload. 
You only need to make sure to exclude /blog path from list of static routes. You can try this https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2719#issuecomment-508583281. Or make `nuxt build && nuxt generate --no-build` command (this way all static routes will be excluded, you'll need to specify them manually).

PS:

> because context.payload is only available to the dynamic routes

I have just tried the method above and it worked.

Comment: i was hesitant to do this first, since it means we would need to add every single route by hand. in the end followed this suggestion, adding both static & dynamic routes in the `generate` function, and passing them the content as `context.payload`.

Comment: used `glob` package to auto collect all routes from `pages` dir, so that we do not have to manually add every new route. now it mirrows nuxt default behavior